# C++ naked function with parameter object

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, inline

I've a class named Person. The Person object has only 1 private property 'Age'. 
I was trying for making a naked assembly function with a parameter of object Person.

That object i want to store in a assemlembly register, and try for taking the property value of age in that stored register.

Storing the object in a register is hopefully well done.

> mov edx, dword ptr ds:[ebp + 0x8]

But now i want to take the property value age, of the object that is been stored in EDX register. 
I tried a few things for picking the value up, but i received always from data.
I only want to do this in inline assembly of registers. without using C++ code in the inline assembly.

person class

```
#include "Person.h"

Person::Person()
{
}

void Person::SetAge(int age)
{
    this->_age = age;
}

int Person::GetAge()
{
    return this->_age;
}




__declspec(naked) void ObjectCall(Person* p)
{
    int age;
    _asm
    {
        mov ebp, esp  // prologue
        push ecx 

        mov edx, dword ptr ds:[ebp + 0x8] // Take full object in parameter and put it in edx register
        mov ecx, 0x4
        mov eax, dword ptr ds:[edx + ecx]   // Trying for taking the property value of age in person object.
        mov age, eax
    }

    std::cout << age << std::endl;
    _asm
    {
// epilogue
        pop ecx
        ret
    }
}

int main()
{
    Person p = Person();
    p.SetAge(5);
    ObjectCall(&p);
}
```

Comment: I am not even sure how or if creating local variables in `naked` functions work. The very purpose of `naked` is to tell the compiler not to create function prologue and stack frame.

Comment: What is the reason for the `naked` function and the inline assembly? What is the *real* and *actual* problem you want to solve with code like that?

Comment: The object person in the parameter is stored in the EDX. i want for taking the property age value in that EDX register and store it back in C++ variable for printing the value.

Comment: Write the function in C++.  Tell the compiler to print the assembly language for the function.  Compare assembly language generated by compiler with yours.